# Hibernate Is Map Fields

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Problem : Cannot insert values into repository because the table relationships are not build correctly.

I have a h2 sql server with spring boot and hibernate building the tables. During creation, there are less tables being created than anticipated. During creation, it groups Customer_foos, StockItems_foos, and Employees_foos into one table. These columns are still assigned in 'table' as if they are still separate.

e.g.{ 
table_foo

```
| table_name not null varchar | Customer_foos_id not null Integer | Customer_foos_key not null varchar | StockItems_foos_id not null Integer | StockItems_foos_values varchar | ...
```

Compared to the desired, where each map would have its own table. Which would avoid the error in inputting null values :

table_Customer_foos

```
| table_name not null varchar | Customer_foos_id not null Integer | Customer_foos_key not null varchar |
```

and table_StockItems_foos

```
| table_name not null varchar | StockItems_foos_id not null Integer | StockItems_foos_key varchar |
```

}

The tables are setup in a pretty staight forward matter with the main entity set up as

```
@Entity
public class table{
    @Id
    @NonNull
    public String 
        Name;

    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @Nullable
    public Map<String, Foo>
        Customer_foos,
        StockItems_foos,
        Employees_foos;

    ...
}
```

with the side entity as

```
@Entity
public class Foo{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer 
        Id;

    @Nullable
    public Double
        Percentage,
        Quantity;

    ...
}
```

Spring 1.4.5 with default dependancies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to circumvent this mishap by making an entity wrapper for each map field, Hibernate then creates a new table for each.

I don't consider this a proper answer, but it works.

As such

```
@Entity
public class Customer_Foos extends Map<String, Foo>{
    ...
}
```